# Translate Rails route to Asp.net MVC route

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I am converting routes from a Rails Application to work with a replacement Asp.net MVC application. We need to maintain all the old urls. Most of the routes convert over without issues - but I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out what to do with this one...

The actual url is all hyphenated like this

```
site.com/agent-name-ratings-city-name-123
```

The Rails Route is defined as

```
get '/:agent_name-ratings-:city-:id' => 'agents#show'
```

I only need to pass the "agent-name" as the {id} to the Asp {agents} controller. My problem is what to do with the city-name and id that come in at the end of the url... ?

I've tried the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "agents", url: "{id}-ratings-{city}-{agent_id}", defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Profiles", id = "{id}" });
```

This works, BUT -- it seems to mess up the @Html.ActionLink...

```
@Html.ActionLink("View",  "Profiles", "Agents",  new { id = item.first_name + "-" + item.last_name }, null)
```

It ends up pointing to...

```
site.com/Agents/Profiles/agent-name
```

which is a valid url, just not the one we want.

SO - How do I get this link in the format that's needed?

```
site.com/agent-name-ratings-city-123
```

The city-name and id are both available from the "item" object. The word "ratings" is a constant. I'm just not sure how to blend it all together.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is you have Url params specified in the route, however they don't appear in your `Html.ActionLink` definition, so the default route gets used as there is no definitive match.

Try the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View",  "Profiles", "Agents",  new { id = item.first_name + "-" + item.last_name, city = item.city, agent_id = item.agent_id }, null)
```

Otherwise, add `UrlParameter.Optional` to the 2 additional fields in the map route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "agents", 
            url: "{id}-ratings-{city}-{agent_id}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Profiles", id = "{id}", city = UrlParameter.Optional, agent_id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

However making the params optional will cause malformed URL's if you only specify the `id` portion in the action link.
e.g. `site.com/agent-name-ratings--`

**Edit**

Also making the Url params optional will most likely break your other routes that are specifying `id` in the params. However this would probably work, and not break too many things, but will still have malformed URL's:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "Profiles", "Agents", new { agent_name = "agent" + "-" + "name" }, null)

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "agents", 
            url: "{agent_name}-ratings-{city}-{agent_id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Agents", action = "Profiles", agent_name = "{agent_name}", city = UrlParameter.Optional, agent_id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```